# error: (-210) warpMatrix must be single-channel floating-point matrix in function cv::findTransformECC

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am pretty sure my images is in greyscale which should be single channel but i am getting this error and have no idea how to work around with it.

```
>>> 
=============== RESTART: C:/Users/310293649/Desktop/resize.py ===============
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/310293649/Desktop/resize.py", line 64, in <module>
    alignment(criteria, warp_mode, warp, nol)
  File "C:/Users/310293649/Desktop/resize.py", line 47, in alignment
    warp = cv2.findTransformECC(im_gray, im1_gray, warp, warp_mode, criteria)
cv2.error: D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.3.0\modules\video\src\ecc.cpp:347: error: (-210) warpMatrix must be single-channel floating-point matrix in function cv::findTransformECC

>>>
```

Below is my code: I am working to speed up my code by creating image pyramid for each images. Scaling the images to smallest get the rough estimate and scale it up.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


path = "R:\\ProcessedPhoto_in_PNG\\"
path1 = "R:\\AlignedPhoto_in_PNG_EUCLIDEAN\\"

nol = 3
warp_mode = cv2.MOTION_EUCLIDEAN
if warp_mode == cv2.MOTION_HOMOGRAPHY :
    warp = np.eye(3, 3, dtype=np.float32)
else :
    warp = np.eye(2, 3, dtype=np.float32)


warp = np.dot(warp, np.array([[1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2], [1/2, 1/2, 1]])**(1-nol))


# Specify the number of iterations.
number_of_iterations = 5000;

# Specify the threshold of the increment
# in the correlation coefficient between two iterations
termination_eps = 1e-10;

# Define termination criteria
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, number_of_iterations,  termination_eps)

def alignment(criteria, warp_mode, warp, nol):

    for i in range(1770,1869):
        for level in range(nol):
            im = cv2.imread(path + 'IMG_1770.png')
            im1 = cv2.imread(path + 'IMG_%d.png'%(i))

            sz = im1.shape


            scale = 1/2**(nol-1-level)

            im_1 = cv2.resize(im, None, fx= scale, fy = scale, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
            im_2 = cv2.resize(im1, None, fx= scale, fy= scale, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

            im_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im_1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            im1_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im_2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

            # Run the ECC algorithm. The results are stored in warp_matrix.
            warp = cv2.findTransformECC(im_gray, im1_gray, warp, warp_mode, criteria)

            if level != nol-1:
            # might want some error catching here to reset initial guess
            # if your algorithm fails at some level of the pyramid

            # scale up for the next pyramid level
                warp = warp * np.array([[1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2], [1/2, 1/2, 1]])

            if warp_mode == cv2.MOTION_HOMOGRAPHY :
                # Use warpPerspective for Homography 
                im1_aligned = cv2.warpPerspective (im1, warp, (sz[1],sz[0]), flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR + cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP)
            else :
                # Use warpAffine for Translation, Euclidean and Affine
                im1_aligned = cv2.warpAffine(im1, warp, (sz[1],sz[0]), flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR + cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP);
            print(i)
            cv2.imwrite(path1 + "AlignedEU_IMG_%d.png"%i , im1_aligned )

alignment(criteria, warp_mode, warp, nol)
```

Comment: convert the variable `warp` to type `np.float32` and then proceed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `warp` matrix was originally of type `np.float32` but then you do a further matrix multiplication with `np.dot` with another matrix not of `np.float32` - not specifying a type defaults to `np.float64` - so the result gets promoted to type `np.float64`.  You need to ensure that the second matrix is also of type `np.float32`.  This is why `findTransformECC` is complaining because it expects the `warp` matrix to be of type `np.float32`, hence the error message.  The easiest way to resolve this is to first create your second matrix to ensure the precision is maintained with `np.float64`, then convert to `np.float32` prior to multiplication when you pass it to `np.dot`:

```
# ....
# ....
nol = 3
warp_mode = cv2.MOTION_EUCLIDEAN
if warp_mode == cv2.MOTION_HOMOGRAPHY :
    warp = np.eye(3, 3, dtype=np.float32)
else :
    warp = np.eye(2, 3, dtype=np.float32)

# New - Create temporary placeholder for new matrix
tmp = np.array([[1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2], [1/2, 1/2, 1]])**(1-nol)

# Matrix multiply with it but ensuring it's of type np.float32
warp = np.dot(warp, tmp.astype(np.float32))

# ....
# ....
# Rest of your code follows
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the function findtransformECC? I saw online a lot of the example mentioned about the cc like this " (cc, warp) = cv2.findTransformECC(im_gray, im1_gray, warp, warp_mode, criteria) " I dont get what is the cc refer to actually..... is it necessary to put that for transformECC function? *Sorry i know this is some question unrelated to the post*

Comment: The function returns a tuple of two elements. You don't have to do that but you'll want to access the second element of the tuple, which is the estimated warp matrix describing the relationship between the images. So you can leave it like you have already, but make sure you do `warp[1]` after to get the matrix. The first element of the tuple is a return code determining how successful the estimation was but if your images are well defined you can ignore the code. However, the input initial estimation to the function also gets mutated upon return, so you can simply not set it equal to anything.